# changing the angle of a 3d orbiting object in relation to the x-axis

Tags: 3d, angle, orbital-mechanics

so i am trying to change the angle at which the object orbits in relation to the x-axis as you are looking down the z-axis. see the picture for what i mean: [image: Angles]

i am currently using this code to orbit the two red spheres:

```
public void orbit() {
    theta += this.vel.x;
    theta = fixAngle(theta, TWO_PI);

    this.loc.x = this.origin.x+orbitRadius*cos(theta);
    this.loc.y = this.origin.y+orbitRadius*cos(theta);
    this.loc.z = this.origin.z+orbitRadius*sin(theta);
  }

  private float fixAngle(float ang, float range) {
    if (ang < 0)
      ang += range;
    else if (ang > range)
      ang -= range;
    return ang;
  }
```

does anyone know how i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it can be done by not rotating the orbiting object but by rotating the coordinate system as answered [HERE](https://forum.processing.org/topic/changing-the-angle-of-an-orbiting-object-in-relation-to-the-x-axis#25080000001224071)